# sIFR 3: IE6 Extra Spacing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, sifr

I'm using sIFR 3 on the following website http://www.bevelite.com.au/test2 which works a charm! The only problem is that I've got a footer div set to sit absolutely at the bottom of the page which it does but once sIFR has finished rendering it puts some extra space below the footer, defeating the purpose of my absolutely positioned footer!

Is there a way I can define the line height of the sIFR rendered text? At the moment the text renders out H1's at 28px high, ideally I would like to set this at 19px high, for both the text before it's rendered out and then after with sIFR.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also remove extra space inside the Flash movie using the `tuneWidth`, `tuneHeight`, `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` arguments to `sIFR.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the `line-height` in your `sifr-config.js`, but I don't think that will have any effect. Try setting the `leading` instead. It takes a value in pixels, but it doesn't take a unit.

For example:

```
css: [
    '.sIFR-root {leading: -2;}'
]
```